# Unable to knit pdf, receiving tinytex error with failed tlmgr search

Tags: r, r-markdown, tinytex

Using 
- RStudio Version 1.2.1335
- R version

I am able to knit the R markdown file to HTML and Word, but fail with PDF. I keep receiving the same error message telling me that it is unable to locate the "Palatino" font.

The file is successfully processed (all chunks run).

I have tried re-installing and resetting Miktex and Tinytex, as well as R itself. I am pretty new to this, so I am unsure how to proceed. Should I install TexLive?

This is the header of the file I am trying to run:

```
--
title: "Assignment 1"
fontsize: 11pt
header-includes: \usepackage{fancyhdr}
geometry: "left=.5in,right=.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    md_extensions: +inline_notes
    number_sections: no
  word_document: default
mathfont: Palatino
monofont: Courier
mainfont: Palatino
sansfont: Helvetica
subtitle: \textbf{Due Wednesday, 11 September 2019 (beginning of class)}
fontfamily: mathpazo
---
```

And this is the error I continue to receive, without rendering of a PDF file:

> output file: PBHLTH252-Assignment-1_post.knit.md
>
> "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS PBHLTH252-Assignment-1_post.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+inline_notes --output PBHLTH252-Assignment-1_post.tex --template "C:\Users\UYser\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine xelatex --variable graphics=yes --lua-filter "C:/Users/UYser/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" --variable "compact-title:yes" 
>   tlmgr search --file --global "/Palatino."
>   ! Package fontspec Error: The font "Palatino" cannot be found.
>
> ! kpathsea: Running mktextfm Palatino
>
> ! The command name is C:\Users\UYser\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktextfm
>
> ! kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
>
> Error: Failed to compile PBHLTH252-Assignment-1_post.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See PBHLTH252-Assignment-1_post.log for more info.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)) :
>     Failed to find a package that contains Palatino.
>   Execution halted

I tried following this thread, https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/81, with no success:

1. Running this suggested code

```
tinytex::tlmgr_search("/Palatino[.](tfm|afm|mf|otf)")
```

results in:

> package repository http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)

2. Running this one

```
tinytex::tlmgr_install("multirow")
```

gives me the following error:

> tlmgr install Palatino.
>   'afm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   tlmgr update --self
>   tlmgr.pl: package repository http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
>   tlmgr.pl: no self-updates for tlmgr available.
>   tlmgr install Palatino.
>   'afm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you got the template from a Mac user while you are on Windows. The fontnames are different there. Instead of `Palatino` you could use `Palatino Linotype`. I am not sure if `Helvetica` and `Courier` will work. If not, you could use `Arial` and `Courier New`.

However, that sounds like a rather ugly font combination. Palatino is a very fine font, but neither Helvertica/Arial nor Courier (New) fit well. Besides, I don't think that normal Palatino fonts are set-up to be used for math. You could use `Asana Math` instead, which comes with MikTeX/TinyTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have similar problems. My solution sounds naive (or silly), but it worked perfectly for me. Instead of debugging, in `RStudio`:

1. install `rticles` package
2. start a new `R Markdown` file
3. choose one of journal article templates such as `PNAS Journal Article`, `Springer Journal Article`, or `Elsevier Journal Article`...
4. `knit` the template.

Then, it will be trying to automatically install missing LaTeX packages...

You may want to try a few journal templates. It worked for me, and I hope this will solve your problem as well. Enjoy it!