# R knit to PDF not working properly with errors

Tags: r, latex, knitr, tinytex

I am trying to knit a document to pdf. I can knit to HTML just fine, but the pdf never works. Things I have tried:

- Update all packages
- install.packages("tinytex")

  - installs perfectly and shows in in the packages pane
- tinytex::install_prebuilt()

```
tlmgr conf auxtrees add "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.3/share/texmf"
Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\XXX XXX\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\tlmgr.bat info --list --only-installed --data name'
```

- tinytex:::install_tinytex()

```
Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\XXX XXX\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\tlmgr.bat info --list --only-installed --data name'
```

- knit button

```
Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\XXX XXX\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\tlmgr.bat update --all --self'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... latexmk_emu -> run_engine -> system2_quiet -> tlmgr_update
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\XXX XXX\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "Document.tex"'
Execution halted
```

- Complete uninstall and reinstall of R and RStudio

I'm at a loss at this point and nothing I have found online has worked.

Metadata sections:

Without xelatex

```
---
title: "A Document"
output: pdf_document
---
```

```
Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\XXX XXX\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\tlmgr.bat update --all --self'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... latexmk_emu -> run_engine -> system2_quiet -> tlmgr_update
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\XXX XXX\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "Document.tex"'
Execution halted
```

With xelatex

```
---
title: "A Document"
output:
   pdf_document:
     latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

```
Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\XXX XXX\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\tlmgr.bat update --all --self'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... latexmk_emu -> run_engine -> system2_quiet -> tlmgr_update
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\XXX XXX\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\xelatex.exe -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "xelatex.tex"'
Execution halted
```

Comment: I've faced this problem and gave up after an hour - I ended up knitting to html then using a converter as a workaround (e.g. https://html2pdf.com/)

Comment: One thing to try is to change the engine. in your yaml put `  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex`     ..  look at one of the rmarkdown cheatsheets for the spacing.

Comment: Also this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829865/unable-to-knit-pdf-receiving-tinytex-error-with-failed-tlmgr-search?rq=1

Comment: Could you include your metadata section in the question?

Comment: I updated the post above. Some things to mention - I can't even install tinytex so that is a big barrier to even knitting the PDF. I have suspicions it could be because I have a space in my user name, but I do not know how to bypass that.

Comment: That's weird. I'm unable to reproduce the problem with a space in username on Windows. Could you also provide your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Another way to bypass this issue is to download TinyTeX to a specific folder in a directory that doesn't contain spaces. I downloaded it to my C: drive and now it works.

Comment: Okay. Good to know. It will still be great if you could provide your `sessionInfo()` in the post, so we could try to reproduce the problem with the appropriate environment (Windows 10?).

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with my file path having a space in it. I went to a different user on my computer which didn't have any spaces and the file converted to a PDF just fine.